# Is there any way to check if the user enters their windows password incorrectly?

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

I'm not sure if it is actually possibe in C#, but I was wondering if there was a way to check everytime the user logs into the computer, and if the password was incorrect, call a function within the program. I'm not sure how tight the security is on things like this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? When a user is logging into Windows, there are obviously no other programs running that could check whether the password was right or not.

Comment: Surely you can run the program as a service? What about if the user had already logged on, and has just locked the workstation?

Comment: ...what are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: I am trying to make a program that monitors for incorrect passwords. Once one is detected, the webcam (if any) connected to the computer captures an image of who is sat at the computer, and logs the date and time of the failed attempt to gain access.

Comment: Alex, I don't know the answer to this question, I'm afraid, but let me just tell you that I find your idea for the app adorable! Very innovative, I think. Good luck with it!

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say *innovative* but...

Comment: Id say atleast George orwell had this idea before the poster.. exaggerated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this would be a good place to start:

[Hook windows logon/logoff events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443244/hook-windows-logon-logoff-events)

I am no expert, but it seems the [callbacks you get from the OS concerning logons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376860%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) are:

- Logon
- Logoff
- StartShell
- DisplayLock
- DisplayUnlock
- StartScreenSaver
- StopScreenSaver

I can't see anything relating to a failed logon attempt, so I guess you'd have to dig deeper - if it's possible at all.